# Could not resolve org.nodejs : Local build error

Tags: node.js, angular, gradle

I have a Angular-App forked from another repository where they manage all their builds in a pipeline.

I wanted to build that in my local system (laptop) and push the built-app in to the hosting server.

This is their `build.gradle`

```
node {
    version = "9.4.0"
    npmVersion = "5.6.0"
    download = true
}

task cleanProd(type: Delete) {
  delete "dist"
}

task testProd(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
  script = file("${projectDir}/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng")
  args = ["test", "--browsers", "PhantomJS", "--watch=false", "--singleRun=true"]
}

task assembleProd(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: ['npmInstall', 'testProd']) {
  script = file("${projectDir}/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng")
  args = ["build", "--prod", "--vendor-chunk=true"]
}

task copyDist(type: Copy) {
  from "dist/"
  into "dist/fancy-ui-${project.version}"
}

task buildProd(dependsOn: [assembleProd])
```

I executed the command `gradlew cleanProd buildProd copyDist` and I am stuck with the below exception

```
Build Version = build-713-ge359ca9
:cleanProd UP-TO-DATE
:nodeSetup FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':nodeSetup'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:9.4.0.
     Required by:
         :portal-ui:build-713-ge359ca9
      > Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:9.4.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/ivy.xml'.
            > Could not GET 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/ivy.xml'.
               > nodejs.org
```

I have all the necessary `HTTP-Proxies` and there is no issue with connectivity as such .. Just that this resource `https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/ivy.xml` is not getting loaded .. but the same code and configuration built fine in the `Jenkins` server

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with node 10.14.1.

There is a workaround that solves the problem:

```
repositories.whenObjectAdded {
    if (it instanceof IvyArtifactRepository) {
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
```

Extracted from https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/301